# Set up event listener for Selenium before everything else

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I'm a newbie to Selenium, but a veteran JS developer, and I'm trying to record a number of times a particular event has fired on an element (let's say `click`) over the entire lifespan of the page.  Is there some way to set up an event listener with Selenium before other JS on the page runs?

I have access to jQuery, but I'm worried that a call to `.ready()` isn't guaranteed to be in place before an earlier `.ready()` triggers a `click` programmatically.  Here's what I've got now:

```
(function () {
    var eventLog = [];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#target-element').on('click', trackEvent);
    });

    function trackEvent(e) {
        eventLog.push(e);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that the element may not have been rendered yet, and you do not want to wait for `body onload` or `DOMContentLoaded` ?

You could kick this listener off early, and it will only `push` to your array for clicks on the `#target-element`

```
  $(document).on('click',function(e) {
       if(e.target.id==='target-element') {
         eventLog.push(e);
      }
    });
```

?

---

In fact , just realised after posting that can use the delegation that the `on()` method provides. - so shorter -

```
  $(document).on('click','#target-element',function(e) {
         eventLog.push(e);
    });
```

Comment: Great solve, Rob.  I got a little snowblinded from all the `.ready()` calls on this page and kind of boxed myself in mentally.  Also, wasn't sure if there was a standard, Selenium-specific way to do this.

Comment: @Impirator, great stuff